# Place a button in Relative layout below the custom zoomview

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to place a Relative layout below the custom Zoomview. I don't want the content of Relative Layout to get Zoom. I want a button to be placed at center of that relative layout.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/images">

<com.example.acer.myapplication.ZoomView
    android:id="@+id/iop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/twentyfive" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why to use relative layout and created nested layout ? you can simply put button below zoomView as you are linearLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/images">

<com.example.acer.myapplication.ZoomView
    android:id="@+id/iop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/twentyfive" />

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Never tested code, but hopefully it will work.

Comment: Thank you. Works as I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/images">

<com.example.acer.myapplication.ZoomView
    android:id="@+id/iop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/twentyfive" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/> //Or use android:layout_centerInParent="true"

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set the orientation of your linear layout as vertical, and directly add the button below it if you necessarily want the relative layout.

Comment: works as I want. Thanks for reply. But have to make changes here and there.